# Access Home Screen from Service

Tags: android, service, navigation, homescreen

I want to do things like open my Appmenu, navigate on the homescreen or pull the notification bar. Is this possible from a service? If yes, how?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  You want to do this stuff automatically without user interaction?

Comment: I don't think it is very nice to do these things. You say you want to open "your" App menu but it is the USERS' App menu...

Comment: I dont want to harm anyone. Lets say i make an App which opens the menu when the user shakes the phone. I dont see anything "wrong" in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. You would have to modify the Android OS itself to do this. This wouldnt be safe from google's perspective to allow this.